# Running a method on self inside a tokio task

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I have created a very simplified example of the code I am having an issue with:

```rust
use core::time;
use std::thread;
use tokio::sync::{mpsc::Receiver, RwLock};

struct MyStruct {
    counter: Arc<RwLock<i32>>,
    rx: RwLock<Receiver<i32>>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    async fn start_here(&self) { // <--------- Lifetime error here on self
        while let Some(message) = self.rx.write().await.recv().await {
            tokio::spawn(self.do_some_work_then_update_counter());
        }
    }

    async fn do_some_work_then_update_counter(&self) {
        let dur = time::Duration::from_millis(10000);
        thread::sleep(dur);
        let mut counter = self.counter.write().await;
        *counter += 1;
    }
}
```

There is a receiver that is receiving messages from another part of the program, and I want to be able to process each message in its own task to prevent blocking the next message from being processed.

As you can imagine it's a lifetime error since the task could outlast self in this case.

One solution I have done is this:

```rust
impl MyStruct {
    async fn start_here(&self) {
        while let Some(message) = self.rx.write().await.recv().await {
            let counter = self.counter.clone();
            tokio::spawn(do_some_work_then_update_counter(counter));
        }
    }
}

async fn do_some_work_then_update_counter(counter: Arc<RwLock<i32>>) {
    let dur = time::Duration::from_millis(10000);
    thread::sleep(dur);
    let mut counter = counter.write().await;
    *counter += 1;
}
```

This just doesn't seem like a good option, I want to keep `do_some_work_then_update_counter` as an impl of `MyStruct` instead of a free function since it is modifying data on `MyStruct`.

I am wondering if there is a better solution to this?

Comment: You cannot savely send your current struct in this scenaro. There are a few ways to go about it. Since you are having counter behind an `Arc` already, you might want to implement `clone`/`copy` for the struct and copy it. You would give a new structure to the task that refer to the same Arc underlying. Alterntively you can use message channels to coordinate incrementing the counter on one thread or you could use a global state behind an RwLock.

Comment: thanks @somnium for the solutions. I think I am going to use messages to make this better. What do you think of creating another tx/rx and passing a tx to `start_here` and then sending a message to the rx which is receiving the messages on the same struct which updates the counter on self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can if you'll return `impl Future` directly instead of being `async fn`:

```rust
fn do_some_work_then_update_counter(&self) -> impl Future<Output = ()> {
    let counter = Arc::clone(&self.counter);
    async move {
        let dur = time::Duration::from_millis(10000);
        thread::sleep(dur);
        let mut counter = counter.write().await;
        *counter += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chayim. Do you mind explaining why this works?

Comment: @AricKuter Why not? I mean, it doesn't capture `self`'s lifetime.

Comment: The difference here is not `async fn` or `impl Future`. By creating a separate reference for `counter`, you are no longer attempting to move `self` into the async closure. Instead, the new reference gets moved and used, until the closure is complete and it is freed. Also, doing `let counter = self.counter.clone();` would work as well.